# Can I edit a totally down-voted question to a good one without compromising the topic

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, suggested-edits, asking-questions

Recently I encountered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641965/puzzle-of-comparing-string-with-numeric-value-to-integer-in-python-if-statement), which doesn't show any research work and was totally unclear.

But I thought to help that guy in clearing the air. So, I wrote an answer, which triggered a thought in me. With proper editing (changing the concept of question to a large extent but not totally), that question could make some sense and might be useful to many novices..

Can I do that?

Comment: if the editing involved is too heavy, a better option would be to post a separate question with [self-answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/self-answer/info "what's this?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to edit the question, make sure you're positive you know exactly what he's asking. Questions are often unclear because of their poor English and can have multiple interpretations depending on how they're deciphered by the reader. If you interpret their question wrong, and then edit the question to clearly ask your interpretation, the entire question will have been compromised and will be rendered useless to the original asker.

Comment: yeah! I even thought about it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can edit improve the question. As long as you keep the spirit of the question alive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be hesitant to do, as you describe:

> changing the concept of question to a large extent

If you change the concept of the question, it's not the same question anymore, is it? Would they be duplicates?

@Gamecat says "keep the spirit", but if you change the concept of the question, it's harldy keeping the spirit...